How to add avatarImg url, before sending the form to database of mongodb
I work on project of blog, with nextjs, mongodb, clerk. The idee very simple just the admin get login and redirct to CreatArticle page and write some word then submited to database by POST http request. after that i use GET http requst to get data from database to showing on the home page. the problem is when the admin enter the data the avatarImg not sending to the database but its showing in the console.log att client
this the code on github
Project on Github
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import {
  ClerkProvider,
  SignInButton,
  SignedIn,
  SignedOut,
  UserButton,
  useAuth,
  useUser,
} from "@clerk/nextjs";
export default function CreatArticlePage() {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const router = useRouter();
  
  // starcture of data sending to database
  const startingArticleData = {
    title: "",
    postImg: "",
    avatarImg: "",
    avatarName: "",
    description: "",
    postBody: "",
  };

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(startingArticleData);

  // show startingArticleData after put postImg url
  console.log(startingArticleData);

  // function of save channges of user on inputs
  const handChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;
    setFormData((preState) => ({
      ...preState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  // function for submite data to database after user cliked on submite button
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await fetch("/api/Articles", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ formData }),
      "content-type": "application/json",
    });
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to create Article.");
    }
    router.refresh();
    router.push("/");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <section className="text-white bg-slate-800">
        <div className="flex justify-center h-screen">
          <form
            className="flex flex-col gap-3 w-full max-w-7xl px-4 py-4"
            method="post"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
            <label>Title: </label>
            <input
              id="title"
              name="title"
              type="text"
              onChange={handChange}
              required={true}
              value={formData.title}
              className="text-slate-900 bg-slate-500"
            />
            <label>Post of Img: </label>
            {/* <input
              id="postImg"
              name="postImg"
              type="file"
              required={true}
              // value={formData.postImg}
              className="text-slate-900 pb-4 bg-slate-500"
              onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files?.[0]) && handChange}
            /> */}
            <label>Description: </label>
            <textarea
              id="description"
              name="description"
              type="text"
              onChange={handChange}
              required={true}
              value={formData.description}
              className="text-slate-900 bg-slate-500"
              rows="3"
            />
            <label>Article: </label>
            <textarea
              id="postBody"
              name="postBody"
              type="text"
              onChange={handChange}
              required={true}
              value={formData.postBody}
              className="text-slate-900 bg-slate-500"
              rows="35"
            />
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="w-full bg-blue-800 hover:bg-blue-700 rounded py-2 mb-4"
              value="creat Ticket"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}


I try to use
  const startingArticleData = {
    title: "",
    postImg: "",
    avatarImg: user ? user.imageUrl : null,
    avatarName: "",
    description: "",
    postBody: "",
  };


to get user Image Profile its work and its show in console log after some waiting
but when i send it to database its show me
{
  _id: '6677596e0d1735d8e2e4e44d',
  title: 'Example for Tite of blog',
  postImg: '',
  avatarImg: null,
  avatarName: 'Full Name',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius itaque sequi illum consequuntur, unde repellat?',
  postBody: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo accusantium nisi nulla, nihil beatae tempora exercitationem eos expedita reiciendis iure natus, molestiae hic nesciunt explicabo? In asperiores illum, sed voluptatibus sapiente odio ad vel iste vero dolores numquam. Impedit, eligendi.',
  createdAt: '2024-06-22T23:08:30.508Z',
  updatedAt: '2024-06-22T23:08:30.508Z',
  __v: 0
}


